# Extract parts of a template into a cpp file

Tags: c++, c++20

When you are building a class template, often the whole of the template needs to be in a header file, which is bad because heavily templated code is hard to reason about, takes long to compile and generates subpar error messages. But often times, parts of the template class that are directly related to the template-arguments can be isolated into a couple small functions and the rest of the code can be regular code that makes calls to these functions when needed:

```
#include <cstddef>

template <class T>
struct Array {
    std::byte* data;
    std::size_t size;
    std::size_t capacity;

    void construct_at(void* p); // 
    void destruct_at(void* p);  // Directly type-related
    size_t obj_size();          // 


    void push_back() {                              // 
        if (size == capacity) {                     //
            // ... resize ...                       //
        }                                           //
        construct_at(data + size * obj_size());     //
        ++size;                                     // Not directly
    }                                               // type related
                                                    //
    void pop_back() {                               //
        auto const off = (size - 1) * obj_size();   //
        destruct_at(data + off);                    //
        --size;                                     //
    }                                               //
};
```

Is there a way to extract parts of this class that are not directly related to the type (push_back, pop_back) into non-templated code that happens to make calls to templated functions (construct_at, destruct_at, obj_size) that somehow do the right-thing for the type at hand?

In theory, this can be done with virtual functions:

```
#include <cstddef>

struct ArrayBase {
    std::byte* data;
    std::size_t size;
    std::size_t capacity;

    virtual void construct_at(void* p) = 0; // 
    virtual void destruct_at(void* p) = 0;  // pure-virtual
    virtual size_t obj_size() = 0;          // 


    void push_back(); //
    void pop_back();  // defined in a cpp file
};


template <class T>
struct Array : ArrayBase {
    void construct_at(void* p) override final {
        new (p) T;
    }

    void destruct_at(void* p) override final {
        static_cast<T*>(p)->~T();
    }

    size_t obj_size() override final {
        return sizeof(T);
    }
};
```

The main issue here is that we need to go through a virtual-table. But in our code, there is no runtime dynamism, it should be possible to avoid that indirection. Is that the case?

Comment: If `push_back` uses templated functions, then it **is** template dependent, at the very least it depends on size of the types in memory

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov my example with virtual functions does go around that.

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov I guess what I am trying to say is that `push_back` does depend on T, but through a more limited API defined by `construct_at` and `obj_size` only. Could this be used get some special treatment?

Comment: It also depends on data members `size`, `capacity` and `data`, which I would discourage you from opening to the public interface

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov of course, this is a simple snippet. I wouldn't have them as public variables in real code.

Comment: If the types, the template may be used with, are limited, you can instantiate the templates without including every member function definition. If not, you could encapsulate the Types used in a class or template class, which has a common base class. And your array just expects a class deriving from that base class. You can use wrapper code to still have correctly typed interfaces.

Comment: You might trade `virtual` with CRTP... but you have again template ;-)

Comment: @Sebastian the types are not limited, and can also be built-in types like int

Comment: @Jarod42 yeah, I did consider CRTP but it doesn't really help...

Comment: On the frontend you can have a proxy class, which provides a nice typed interface. On the backend you want a general implementation. So you have to generate an configuration object (not only a type, otherwise you would get templates again), which describes the type (e.g. size) and provides functions (for construction, destruction). You can make this approach typed again by making this object a template, but deriving from a common base class. You would need one instance of this object; the provided member functions may not be static as there are no static virtual member functions in C++.

Comment: The backend implementation would know the common base class and use that object as representative of it to call its needed (virtual) functions and to ask for the size or other type parameters it needs.

Comment: @Sebastian Interesting. Do you mean something like this: https://godbolt.org/z/3qa9ed1sr

Comment: Actually, not quite, see answer. But the one you posted is also an interesting solution, but wouldn't `Array` have to go in the header again as it is templated?

Comment: @Sebastian Array itself would go into a header file, but definitions of ArrayBase functions can be moved into source files.

Comment: I do not think that they could be moved.

Comment: @Sebastian in that code, you can see that definitions of the non-templated push_back(size_t) and pop_back(size_t) are omitted, thus moved into a cpp file.

Comment: If their logic only requires the size and you provide the size as input parameter, it would be a solution.

Comment: @Sebastian and the rest of the logic is done by the calling wrapper-method. Hoping that part is relatively simple

Comment: If `push_back` “happens to make calls to [different specializations of] templated functions” and not by runtime indirection, it is by necessity a templated function itself.  What you want is fundamentally impossible.

Answer (score 1):

One solution, that is not very general but is applicable sometimes is to create a non-type-safe version of the class that directly works with bytes, and then create a type-safe version that wraps around the complicated logic:

```
#include <cstddef>

struct ArrayBase {
private:
    std::byte* data;
    std::size_t size_in_byes;
    std::size_t capacity_in_bytes;

protected:

    void* push_back(size_t bytes);  // Complicated logic is
    void* pop_back(size_t bytes);   // moved to a .cpp file
};

template <class T>
struct Array : private ArrayBase {
    void push_back() {
        auto p = push_back(sizeof(T));
        new (p) T;
    }

    void pop_back() {
        auto p = pop_back(sizeof(T));
        static_cast<T*>(p)->~T();
    }
};
```

This is viable if the non-type-safe version is significantly more complex than the type-safe version.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right then you wonder if `ArrayBase::push_back()` can avoid going through the virtual table to call `Array::construct_at()`. But if the goal is to reduce the size of the header and improve compile times then that is a clear NO, unless you use LTO (link time optimization).

If you have `push_back()` in it's own compilation unit and compile it only once then there is no way for the compiler to know what version of `construct_at` is the right one to call when compiling `push_back()`. There is also no way for the compiler to inline the call to `push_back()` when it is used and it knows the type `T`.

The exception to this is when you use LTO, since then the whole source basically turns into a single compilation unit at link time and all sorts of whole program optimizations can happen, including deducting and eliminating virtual function calls into static calls (or inlineing said calls).

Similar if you leave the whole code in the header. But then what was the point if splitting out the non-template parts?

Comment: I am fine with using LTO. I have not tested if LTO eliminates the vtable indirection though. I'd be willing to know if you have any solutions involving LTO.

Comment: Whether LTO will eliminate the vtable call depends on the compiler and actual code. That's something you just have to test and keep retesting on every change. I have no idea how reliable that optimization will be.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to extract is when methods are really not related to template.

You might try to remove dependencies to type in several ways.

`virtual` as you have done, or try function pointers, something like:

```
#include <cstddef>

struct ArrayBase {
    std::byte* data;
    std::size_t size;
    std::size_t capacity;

#define OPTION moreReadableOption
#if OPTION == 1
    void push_back(void (*construct_at)(void*));
    void pop_back(void (*destruct_at)(void*));
#elif OPTION == 2
    void push_back(std::type_identity_t<void(void*)>* construct_at);
    void pop_back(std::type_identity_t<void(void*)>* destruct_at);
else
    using construct_at_func = void(void*);
    using destruct_at_func = void(void*);

    void push_back(construct_at_func* construct_at);
    void pop_back(destruct_at_func* destruct_at);
#endif

};

template <class T>
struct Array : ArrayBase {
    static void construct_at(void* p) { new (p) T; }
    static void destruct_at(void* p) { static_cast<T*>(p)->~T(); }
    static size_t obj_size() { return sizeof(T); }

    void push_back() { ArrayBase::push_back(&construct_at); }
    void pop_back() { ArrayBase::pop_back(&destruct_at); }
};
```

cpp files:

```
void ArrayBase::push_back(void (*construct_at)(void*))
{
    if (size == capacity) {
        // ... resize ...
    }
    construct_at(data + size * obj_size());
    ++size;
}

void ArrayBase::pop_back(void (*destruct_at)(void*)) {
    auto const off = (size - 1) * obj_size();
    destruct_at(data + off);
    --size;
}
```

Comment: And how is this better than a vtable indirection?

Comment: I would say it is similar.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

Header:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <memory>

struct TypeConfBase {
    virtual void construct_at(void* p) = 0; // 
    virtual void destruct_at(void* p) = 0;  // pure-virtual
    virtual size_t obj_size() = 0;          // 
};

template <class T>
struct TypeConf : TypeConfBase {
    void construct_at(void* p) override final {
        new (p) T;
    }

    void destruct_at(void* p) override final {
        static_cast<T*>(p)->~T();
    }

    size_t obj_size() override final {
        return sizeof(T);
    }
};
```

CPP File (struct definition of course has to be in header to use it):

```
struct ArrayBase {
    std::unique_ptr<TypeConfBase> typeconf;

    std::byte* data;
    std::size_t size;
    std::size_t capacity;

    void push_back(); //
    void pop_back();  // defined in a cpp file
};
```

Comment: This still has the same vtable indirection as in my example though

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili You cannot have both. If `push_back` and `pop_back` are in a cpp file instead of a header and the used types are not known beforehand (and the optimizer cannot do tricks with link-time-optimization), they will be fixed functions. `push_back` and `pop_back` need access to `construct_at`, `destruct_at` and the `size` as function or value somehow. If not per vtable, then as function function parameters to `push_back` and `pop_back`. It does not matter, which class is member or base class of which other class. You cannot have fixed code with flexible types, but no indirection.

Comment: Well, if it was a simple matter, I wouldn't be asking it here ;)